# Input File change checked JQuery при одинаковом втором выборе

Tags: html, jquery

**Есть код HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input id="f_fileDoc" name="fileDoc" type="file"/>
</form>
```

И `JavaScript + jQuery`:

```
$("#f_fileDoc").change(function () {
  var fileName = $(this).val();
  alert(fileName);
});
```

Он работает только если следующий файл выбран не такой, как предыдущий. Хотелось бы сделать некий багфикс при многократном одинаковом выборе.

Comment: А что именно должно происходить? какой конечный ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Может есть смысл просто при клике очищать значение val? 
$("#f_fileDoc").click(function() {
 fileName.val('')
});

Comment: @NeedHate конечный результат мне нужно обрабатывать все файлы, которые выбрал пользователь, даже если он выбрал первый раз файл, а потом выбрал его ещё раз. Если он выбирает 2 разных файла, то это обрабатывается нормально. Боюсь DOM объект не даст мне поменять val input file. Защита в браузере сработает. Попробую завтра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может поможет кому-нибудь:

```
$("#f_fileDoc").change(function () {
  var fileName = $(this).val();
  alert(fileName);
  $("#f_fileDoc").parent().html($("#f_fileDoc").parent().html());
});
```